# Matplotlib not showing histogram correctly when saving figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, figure

Using matplotlib, I am plotting 2 histograms in one figure. The goal is to add them to a Latex document later. I am interested in the difference between the two, so I use a low transparency and plot them on top of each other. In Spyder, when I plot inline, the image looks fine. See [wanted plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMxP2.png)

[image: wanted]

When I export the image as a PNG using `plt.savefig()`, the image looks like this. However, this does not work well in Latex documents as the scaling gets ruined. When I try to export it as a PDF file, the bars of the histogram seem to overlap, making it seem like it has edges, like in [ugly plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2hAC.png).

[image: ugly]

I think the cause of the problem is due to the vector format, when zooming in and out of the PDF, the overlap changes. When zoomed in completely, it looks identical to the PNG, when zoomed out the overlap becomes much larger. I would be very grateful if anyone knew the solution to this.

Things I have tried already:

- changing linewidth/edgecolor
- changing the matplotlibrc file
- changing the distance of the bins using rwidth

Code I am using:

```
    binwidth = (np.max(prediction) - np.min(prediction)) / (2*I**(1/3))
    kwargs = dict(alpha=0.5, bins=np.arange(min(prediction), max(prediction) + binwidth, binwidth))
    
    fig_path = '***.pdf'

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.hist(prediction.flatten(), **kwargs, label = 'NN')
    ax.hist(hedging_error, **kwargs, label = 'BS')
    ax.set_xlim((-3,3))
    ax.set_xlabel('Hedging error')
    ax.set_ylabel('Count')
    ax.legend()
    fig.savefig(fig_path)
```

Comment: Does setting `linewidth` to zero or your `edgecolor` to 'none' help?

Comment: _the bars of the histogram seem to overlap, making it seem like it has edges_ those edges, outlining the bars, which are the bins of the histogram, make the visualization more clear.

Comment: @ParthShah Unfortunately not, at first I thought it was simply the edge that was the problem, but those are turned off already

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bin edges use `plt.hist(..., histtype='stepfilled')`

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/histogram_histtypes.html